# Partitions mounted as read-only, problem with the fstab file

Tags: fstab

This is my `/etc/fstab` file after my experiment with it.

```
proc                                       /proc            proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid                                          0  0  
UUID=140bf3f9-51f1-4894-8aa8-0682f2faccaf  /                ext4  errors=remount-ro                                            0  1  
UUID=f908bcb0-d211-49ac-9980-45822fece574  none             swap  users,sw,user                                                0  0  
/dev/fd0                                   /media/floppy0   auto  rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8                                     0  0  
/dev/sda5                                  /media/sda5      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,users,user                                     0  0  
/dev/sdb1                                  /media/sdb1      vfat  users,user                                                   0  0  
/dev/sda3                                  /media/sda3      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,users,umask=000,user                           0  0  
/dev/sda4                                  /media/sda4      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,users,user                                     0  0  
/dev/sda6                                  /media/sda6      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,users,umask=000,user                        0  0  
/dev/sda7                                  /media/sda7      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,users,umask=000,user                        0  0  
/dev/sda8                                  /media/sda8      ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,ro,users,umask=000,user                        0  0  
/dev/sda1                                  /media/Classics  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,group,users,umask=000,gid=users,user,uid=root  0  0
```

Now my partitions are mounted as read-only. There is some problem with `sdb1` also, every time I have to press S to boot. Please help me to edit `fstab` to its default state.

Comment: You can just place a `#` in front of the line `/dev/sdb1  /media/sdb1  vfat  users,user  0 0` to comment it out or remove the line..

Comment: The mount manual page says: `If the msdos filesystem detects an inconsistency, it reports an error and sets the file system read-only. The filesystem can be made writable again by remounting it.` So, you can open a terminal and unmount the partition with: `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` and then remount those defined in fstab with `sudo mount -a`

Answer (score 0):

For remounting the root file-system with read/write access use:

> sudo mount -o remount,rw /